# Is there any good project management tool base on django?

Tags: python, django, project-management

As I know trac is a good project manage tool in python world,
but I want a simple one.

Comment: nothing   I just want a sample one  beacuse my Collaborator are not Programmer

Comment: Do you want to use it or actually modify it for a custom requirement? Using it is quite easy even for non programmers.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim plenty of things.

Comment: i think by sample you mean simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[django-projector](https://bitbucket.org/lukaszb/django-projector/src) maybe worth a try.

Comment: django-projector looks abandoned. At this moment there are none except Trac, and as python says, is not generic, but especialized for developers.

Comment: Yeah there isn't anything good in the django world, you have to go rails unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://code.google.com/p/django-project-management/ ?

Rails has some amazing ones though that I would recommend like open project and red mine. I wish there were Django equivalents of these. I will be deploying them once I get more familiar with rails.  Turnkey has a redmine image which serves as an alternative to manual installation. http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/10220